# iPhone - OARequestHeader warnings

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, image, twitpic

I am trying to upload a picture to TwitPic using GSTwitPicEngine.
I have included all the requirements but it seems that some functions used in OARequestHeader class are not recognized. Here is an example:

```
[chunks addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"realm=\"%@\"", [realm encodedURLParameterString]]];
```

The "encodedURLParameterString" function is not recognized. realm variable is a NSString.

Do you have any idea what I have done wrong?

Thanks, 
Andrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YEP!

You are missing one file or missed to include it (it's part of OAuthConsumer).
Simply download

```
NSString+URLEncoding.h
```

and

```
NSString+URLEncoding.m
```

from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c1/OAuthConsumer/NSString+URLEncoding.h
and http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c1/OAuthConsumer/NSString+URLEncoding.m

and add the #import line into the file, where the error appeared:

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"
```

This will add "encodedURLParameterString" to NSStrings selectors.